# Can we create a new user with sufficient permissions to connect on a AWS machine that does not need to use a PEM to RDP/SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, key-pair

Once connecting to a AWS server using the PEM keypair (either RDP or SSH) if we add a new user with local administrator permissions will we be able to logon/SSH without using the original PEM keypair?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In fact, it is recommended that once an Amazon EC2 Linux instance is launched, the keypair used for authentication should be **replaced with your standard corporate security method**.

This might mean creating local users and copying their personal keypairs to their `~.ssh/authorized_keys` file, or it might mean using an **LDAP or AD server** to provide authentication services.

Quick explanation:

- When somebody uses SSH with a keypair to login to a Linux instance, the SSH server looks in the requested user's `~.ssh/authorized_keys` file. It then tries to match the public keypairs in the file with the private keypair used to establish the SSH session.
- If they match, then the login is permitted
- Therefore, you can simply replace the keypairs in that file with any desired keypair

This keypair authentication process is a Linux standard and actually has nothing to do with Amazon EC2 itself. However, a helper script on Amazon Linux AMIs will copy the selected keypair into the `authorized_keys` file on first boot, to make it easier for users to initially login to the instance.